# HTTP Error 500.19 and Web Project Properties Window Managed Pipeline Mod Missing

Tags: webforms, application-pool, applicationhost

I have this web project, itt starts to throw ERROR (HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error), and when I check for the View->Properties Window. I found that option (Managed Pipeline Mode) is missing.

[image]
[image]

This application is configured in IIS7

To trouble shoot this ERROR, I have already granted full controls to user accounts (IUSR, ASPNET)

Any suggestions are Welcome !

Thanks & Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I have switched from IIS 7 to IIS Express, and the error goes away.